# Pass struct into function as its individual attributes

Tags: c

I want to pass a structure into a (recursive) function and each time it calls the function I want to change the values of the attributes it gets without updating the actual values in the previous scope.

Here is some sample code. Would this be a correct way to implement this? (Specific help needed on the function call in the "Function" file.

**Header File**

```
typedef struct Pos {
  int x;
  int y;
} Pos;

bool func1(Pos vars, int step);
```

**Main**

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  Pos vars = {.x = 0, .y = 0};

  if (func1(vars, 0)) {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**Function**

```
bool func1(Pos vars, int step) {
  if (step == 2) {
    return true;
  }

  func1({.x += 1, .y += 2}, step+1);

  printf("%d %d", vars.x, vars.y);

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Arguments which are not passed by address are automatically copied so each invocation has a copy and will not affect the callers copy.

Comment: `func1({.x += 1, .y += 2}, step+1);` --> `func1((Pos){vars.x + 1, vars.y + 2}, step+1);` or `func1((Pos){vars.x += 1, vars.y += 2}, step+1);` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a 'compound literal', which looks like a cast before an initializer:

```
bool func1(Pos vars, int step) {
    if (step == 2) {
        return true;
    }

    func1((Pos){.x = vars.x + 1, .y = vars.y + 2}, step+1);

    printf("%d %d", vars.x, vars.y);

    return true;
}
```

This feature was added to C99 — but since you're attempting to use designated initializers, that presumably isn't a problem to you.

---

<sup>*I see that [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) pointed out this notation in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494011/pass-struct-into-function-as-its-individual-attributes/42498217#comment72127346_42494011) that I didn't read until after adding this answer.

I've made this Community Wiki.*</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Here is a code, maybe it can help you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;


typedef struct Pos {
    int x;
    int y;
} Pos;

Pos * initializeStruct (int x1, int y1) {
    Pos * vars = new Pos();
    vars->x = x1 + 1;
    vars->y = y1 + 2;
    return vars;
}

bool func1(Pos *, int );

int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    Pos *vars = new Pos();
    vars->x = 0;
    vars->y = 0;

    if (func1(vars, 0)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool func1(Pos *vars, int step) {
    if (step == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    func1(initializeStruct(vars->x, vars->y), step+1);

    printf("%d %d\n", vars->x, vars->y);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Note that you've given a C++-only answer to a question that is tagged C.  That's not dreadfully constructive.  (Also, snippet markup is not helpful for C or C++ code — don't use it on such questions.)